# Extract data from excel file to sharepoint list once uploaded in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow, excel, modern-experience

We have a requirement that when an excel file will be uploaded into SharePoint document library, all its data should be captured and should be moved to separate lists accordingly.

for example: if we have two fields called "user" and "user access" in excel then after uploading of excel file into SharePoint library, "users" field values should be created in a separate "users" list and "user access" field values should be created in access list of SharePoint. How to extract those details? Is workflow can do that or any other way?

below is the sample input of excel file to be uploaded:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps for your reference:

Step1: Format the excel file as table refer to this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-an-excel-table-6789619f-c889-495c-99c2-2f971c0e2370), the result looks like this:
[image]

Step2:Create a flow to list rows present in a table, apply to each to cycle the table and create new item in different lists using differnent column name.

[image]

Comment: what is the name of the flow template that we need to use here?

Comment: Currently there is no official template to meet your requirement, it's customized steps for your reference.

Comment: flow is working fine now but failing while getting a Date field from excel table as it is considering that as a string? Could you please let me know how to avaid this  issue?

Comment: Add an asterisk before date in excel,such as *3/18/2020

Comment: tried with *3/18/2020 still not accepting the format. @Julie_MSFT

Comment: it is working now when i have changed the field type in excel table to "Text" Thanks Julie